# How can I bind to the length of a ListProperty?

Tags: python, user-interface, events, kivy

My simplified code (there's also a `GameWorld` class which is the root widget):

```
class Player(Entity):
    # done like this so `ammo` is a readonly property
    _ammo = ListProperty()
    ammo = AliasProperty(lambda self: self._ammo, bind=['_ammo'])
```

KV file:

```
<GameWorld>:
    player: the_player

    Player:
        id: the_player
        center: root.center

    Label:
        text: str(len(the_player.ammo))
        top: root.top
```

The amount of ammo should be updated automatically on the screen. It doesn't. This is because `ammo` is bound to `_ammo`, but the latter never really changes. It always stays the same list object, with changing contents.

What would be the good practice Kivy solution  to this problem?

EDIT:

Meanwhile, I found the following solution. I trigger the event associated with `ammo` myself. Anywhere in the code the ammo might change, I added this line:

```
self.__class__.ammo.dispatch(self)
```

I access `ammo` through `self.__class__` because that gives me the `ListProperty` object, as opposed to the list. I then call `dispatch(self)` on it to broadcast that this property has changed. The GUI is then notified and updated.

It'll be awesome if anybody has a better way :)

Comment: `ammo_count = AliasProperty(lambda self:len(self._ammo))` maybe?

Comment: @JoranBeasley This won't work because, how can the GUI know when `ammo_count` changes in order to update the Label? This is the point of this question. I need to way for the property to broadcast an event when the contents of `self._ammo` change, or at least is length.

Comment: oh I see ... I usually just hardcode as much of my stuff as I can into actual classes, and I try to avoid the .kv language usually

Comment: @JoranBeasley Really? I find the language is useful just because it saves you from doing most of the horrible binding stuff yourself.

Comment: First, the (IMHO) better, and [documentation-suggested](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.property), and easier-to-understand way to access a property is through `instance.property('property_name')`, so in your case `self.property('ammo')`.

Comment: Second, if you didn't enforce read-only, there'd be no issue: using `text: str(len(the_player._ammo))` updates as expected. But if you insist on doing it that way, maybe the solution below works for you. Certainly better than adding an arbitrary line of code at every location of manipulation...

Comment: It seems like you arrived to the python world from java world, and have to put everywhere setters, getters and private pools, or else you would die like a fish without water. This isn't necessary in python, and in many cases, like this one, could be (or should be) avoided.

Comment: As observed by others, you shouldn't use the AliasProperty, just use a single ListProperty and call len to get its length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another `AliasProperty`:

```
ammo_count = AliasProperty(lambda self: len(self._ammo), bind=['_ammo'])
```

This will update every time `_ammo` changes its length.